# Windows command line - can't copy text

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to copy the output of a shell script to the clipboard. I right-click, select Mark, select the desired text, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> into a Notepad file, but there's nothing to be pasted.

What am I doing wrong? This worked until recently.

Comment: FYI, Ctrl+C is the break function for the command prompt, so it cant be used for cutting and pasting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> , simply right click on selected text and it will copy to clipboard automatically.

Comment: Why in the world did they change it from Ctrl + C to right-clicking to copy? This is so much harder to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

To copy CMD line text to the clip board --

In the upper left of the CMD line Window, click on the black "C:\" icon --> Edit --> Mark

Then use the mouse to highlight what you want to copy to the clipboard

Press ENTER

Move the mouse to where you to paste and then CTRL-V

Comment: If you have QuickEdit mode turned on you don't even need to explicitly select Mark every time. Simply select with the mouse and right-click.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click in the command prompt > Click "Mark" > Click and Drag over what you want to copy

Now you can paste this text with Ctrl+v.

Comment: You have missed a part of the procedure in your answer. After you **`Click and Drag`** to select what you want to copy, you have to either **`Right-click`** on the selection, or press the **`[Enter]`** key, which will place the selection on the clipboard. **Then** you can perform the paste operation.